# vector substitution in numpy/python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, vector

Given two vectors `v=['a','b','c']` and `i=np.random.randint(len(v),size=10)`, I can get the "substitution" vector

```
vi = [v[i[x]] for x in range(len(i))]
```

E.g., `vi` is

```
['a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'a']
```

if

```
i = array([0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0])
```

Is there a *vectorized* operation for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use numpy indexing (note that you need to convert `v` to a `numpy.array` for this to work):

```
v = np.array(['a','b','c'])
i = np.random.randint(len(v),size=10)

>>> v[i]
array(['c', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], dtype='<U1')
```

***Timings***

```
In [26]: i = np.random.randint(len(v),size=1000000)

In [27]: %timeit [v[i[x]] for x in range(len(i))]
554 ms ± 6.41 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [28]: %timeit v[i]
4.85 ms ± 12.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [29]: %timeit [v[s] for s in i]
505 ms ± 1.95 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: can you also compare what (imo) *most* would do, `[v[s] for s in i]`?

Comment: Done.  Looks like it trims a bit of overhead

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Once again `numpy` proving too fast..